# Retrieve Schema Validation Values | Mongoose Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

let us say that I have this simple Schema in Node js

```
const example = new mongoose.Schema({
  type: {
    type: String, 
    enum: ['apple', 'orange', 'bannana']
  }
})
```

How can I retrieve the array(enum) validation for the Type field?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const exampleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  type: {
    type: String, 
    enum: ['apple', 'orange', 'banana']
  }
});

const Example = mongoose.model('Example', exampleSchema);
const typePath = Example.schema.path('type');

console.log(typePath.enumValues);
```

**Result**:  `['apple', 'orange', 'banana']`